# Probability that a random variable with bounded moments is at least epsilon

Tags: probability-theory

The real-valued random variable $X$ satisfies:

(i) $E[X] \geq 0$

(ii) $E[X^2] \geq a$

(iii) $E[X^{2+\delta}] \leq N$

for some $a,N,\delta >0$. Must there exist $\epsilon,\epsilon'>0$, depending only on $a,\delta,N$, such that $P[X \geq \epsilon] \geq \epsilon'$ ?

It is easy to see that all 3 conditions are necessary. For example if (ii) is omitted we can let $X=0$ almost surely and if (iii) is omitted we can let $X=0$ with probability $1-1/n$ and $X=n$ with probability $1/n$.